# Redirect Laravel 8 Fortify

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-fortify

I need some help with redirects after login with Laravel 8 Fortify.  I know how to do it in a login controller but with Fortify there is a LoginResponse that I am not sure how to do this.  I know in RouteService Provider I can change it to whereever but I have roles that I want to redirect to different dashboards based on role.
In the old Login Controller I would do the following.  How would I change this to the LoginResponse for Fortiy?

```
public function redirectTo()
    {
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
                $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('manager')){
                $this->redirectTo = route('manager.dashboard');
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('employee')){
                $this->redirectTo = route('employee.dashboard');
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did the below answer your question or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Customize Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects) with `Fortify` by binding your own implementation of the `LoginResponse`. You could add the following to the `register` method of your `FortifyServiceProvider`:

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse;

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->instance(LoginResponse::class, new class implements LoginResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            if($request->user()->hasRole('admin')){
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            if($request->user()->hasRole('manager')){
                return redirect()->route('manager.dashboard');
            }
            if($request->user()->hasRole('employee')){
                return redirect()->route('employee.dashboard');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you'd prefer you can always create the class in an actual file  instead of using an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php).

---

Here is a [Laravel News post](https://laravel-news.com/override-login-redirects-in-jetstream-fortify) that goes into it in a little more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a custom dashboard for each role, if it were me instead of changing the under the hood as Rwd suggested I would make my default redirect page which is in  /config/fortify.php as the home directory to be the page that handles the redirect. So your ***route('dashbord')*** will decide which dashboard the user needs:

```
Route::middleware([...])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
          if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
                $redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('manager')){
                $redirectTo = route('manager.dashboard'); 
            }
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('employee')){
                $redirectTo = route('employee.dashboard'); 
            }
            return redirect()->to($redirectTo);
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```